# How to fix React Native Flow Throw Error is Missing Null or Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, flowtype

I am taking a class on `React Native`. I am using `Atom` with `Nuclide` and `Flow` for making the projects. I am following the instructor, but after each piece of lesson I am trying to remove all errors Flow throws at me. But I am really stuck on this piece. I get this error message:

> ***Cannot get prevState.selectedPlace.key because property key is missing in null or undefined.***

Below is my code and I marked out which line Im getting the error which happens in the `placeDeletedHandler` function.

```
/**
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

import PlaceInput from "./src/components/PlaceInput/PlaceInput.js";
import PlaceList from "./src/components/PlaceList/PlaceList.js";
import PlaceDetail from "./src/components/PlaceDetail/PlaceDetail.js"

type Props = {};
type State = {
  places: Array<Object>,
  selectedPlace: ?{
    key: string,
    name: string,
    image: Image
  }
};
export default class App extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    places: [],
    selectedPlace: null,
  };

  placeAddedHandler = (placeName: string) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
            places: prevState.places.concat({
              key: String(Math.random()),
              name: placeName,
              image: {
                uri: "https://cdn.newsapi.com.au/image/v1/f08d8ccc83fbc2d08529aea69890ad4d?width=1024"
              }
            })
        };
      });
  };

  placeDeletedHandler = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          places: prevState.places.filter(place => {
              return place.key !== prevState.selectedPlace.key; <-- Error on this line
            }),
            selectedPlace: null
        };
      });
  };

  modalClosedHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      selectedPlace: null
    });
  };

  placeSelectedHandler = (key : string) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        selectedPlace: prevState.places.find(place => {
          return place.key == key;
        })
      };
    });

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <PlaceDetail
          selectedPlace={this.state.selectedPlace}
          onItemDeleted={this.placeDeletedHandler}
          onModalClosed={this.modalClosedHandler}
        />
        <PlaceInput onPlaceAdded={this.placeAddedHandler}/>
        <PlaceList
          places={this.state.places}
          onItemSelected={this.placeSelectedHandler}
        />
      </View>
      );
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 26,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },


});
```

I'm sure someone else might have similar problems. And I dig around the internet for hours trying to solve it. The closest thing I found was this link: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6954

If anyone can help solve this and explain why it's happening, I would like to know and sure others doing this would like to know as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [maybe type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/) in your state:

```
type State = {
   selectedPlace: ?{ key: string, ...}
   ...
  }
```

- question mark means that `selectedPlace` might be `null` or `undefined`. So `flow` expects you to have safety check that `selectedPlace` is defined, the easiest way might be something like:

```
return prevState.selectedPlace && place.key !== prevState.selectedPlace.key
```

Or, you can unmark maybe type from `selectedPlace`.

Comment: Needed to keep selected place an optional as its null. So your fixed seemed to work perfectly. Thanks.